# Linking to MS-Visio page from within MS-Word (all 2010)

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, ms-office, visio, office-2010

I must not be searching for the right terms, because I haven't found an answer yet.  I have both Word & Visio 2010, and want to be able to link a page in Visio (or a portion of one) to a Word document, so when changes are made in Visio they are synched when the Word doc is opened.

What would be even better was if there was a way to link a portion of one of those Visio pages into the Word document.  The Visio documents have multiple pages (describing independent flows).  Also, portions of each of the flows is dependent on another flow on the same page.

```
For example:
Visio Document has 2 pages, each with different flows on them.  (Flows=process).  
In the Word document, I want to describe in detail, and show the correct page or 
portion thereof.  If Visio page1 has 3 flows/processes on it, I would like to 
be able to reference each flow/process independently. As in,

Step 1 - do this
{link to portion of Visio Page1 I am describing}
Step 2 - do that
{link to portion of Visio Page1 I am describing}
Step 3 - do something else
{link to portion of Visio Page1 I am describing}

If that isn't possible, then I would like to be able to reference the specific 
Visio page in my Word document.
```

As it is, I think I can link to the Visio document in its entirety, but I think that it only displays the active page when it was last saved.

Comment: I've tried that since I read your response, but have not been able to get it to work, either locally or when connected to Sharepoint.  It looks like there is limited functionality & defines the word "Klunky" as a solution.